# Post to Twitter through API

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to figure out how to let my users post a tweet by following a link on my site. This is the process I design:

1. A link somewhere on my site will have an offer: "Send a Twit and receive a coupon".
2. Once they click on the offer link, they are redirected to Twitter for authorization.
3. After they grant a permission to connect with their Twitter profile, I would like to send a post using Twitter API, with a pre-populated message, something like: "Trying out this online tool for free: http"//mylink.com". After the message is posted they need to be redirected back to my site to a page with a coupon code.

I got about 75% done so far.

1. I installed [twitterOauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/)
2. Based on demo examples I can now do the following:
   -- Link to Twitter ([DEMO](http://www.usabilitest.com/incl/classes/twoauth/connect.php))
   -- Login the user with Twitter
   -- Redirect back to my site

What I still need to figure out is how to post the Tweet... Ideally I would like to show the message that will be posted, but without a functionality to edit it, just to let them know. I can possibly show it on the first page, which means I'd like to post it automatically once they grant permission to Twitter, right before redirecting to the coupon code. Where do I add POST functionality?

Here's the return.php code.

```
<?php
/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

// This is where we end up when the user comes back from twitter.
// First, we creat a new connection object
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
// Then we use it to send a twitter message

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test message'));

// Finally, we redirect the user to the coupon page
header('Location: /privacy'); // Supplies user with coupon
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Twitter redirects the user back to your site, send the Tweet then load the page with the coupon code. Although make sure the you've informed the user that their status will be updated if they authorize your app.

You forgot exchanging for the access_tokens:

```
<?php
/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

// This is where we end up when the user comes back from twitter.
// First, we creat a new connection object
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

$token_credentials = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token_credentials['oauth_token']
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $token_credentials['oauth_token_secret'];

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

// Then we use it to send a twitter message

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test message'));

// Finally, we redirect the user to the coupon page
header('Location: /privacy'); // Supplies user with coupon
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I will make it clear upfront before they even go to Twitter and even show the text of the update. What I am struggling with is how to post the message. Please see my updated question with code.

Comment: @santa Check the code that I added in lines 11-13, for getting the access token.

Comment: I am using the same code. Using this code, user can post on their twitter page after logging in, but i want to post on my page without the login functionality. How can i do so?